# ALB rules limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

We are developing a microservices architecture with Amazon Webservices ECS and Application Load Balancer (ALB). The ALB has a rule per domain which couples a path pattern to a TargetGroup. For example:

```
/user* -> tg-user-service
/image* -> tg-image-service
/email* -> tg-email-service
... etc
```

This works pretty neat and saves us maintaining a separate service discovery service.
However, today I found out that one ALB has a **limit of 10 rules**. This made me question if we are using the ECS/ALB approach correctly. Also, how can I mitigate this? All traffic is handled by one ALB.

**EDIT:
AWS Seems to have increased the limit to 75. Thank you AWS!**

Comment: Please note that in April 2017, AWS increased the ALB rule limit from 10 to 75.  More information is available here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/

Comment: It's 100 now - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I got this answer back from AWS regarding my rule limit increase request:

> Hello,
>
> I apologize for the confusion with this limit increase. Unfortunately,
>   Application Load Balancers have a hard rule limit of 10. I apologize
>   that this was not made clear to you sooner. Please let us know if you
>   have any further questions or concerns.
>
> Best regards,

Comment: In April 2017, the limit was increased to 75: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/

Comment: And it's now 100

Answer (score 1):

Many AWS Limits are what they consider Soft Limits... meaning you can ask AWS to raise the limit and they will do it.  These look like soft limits as well. You can see a list of all the limits [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html) and there is a link to raise the limit.

As far as your use case, you are doing exactly what the service is meant for.

Comment: OK, I'll do that thanks. Its a bit funny that considering a microserviceS architecture the limit is only 10.

Comment: They don't do that, the rules limit is hard, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon is still pulling together its documentation regarding the ELB and the ELBv2 (ALB). As a result its a good idea to cross reference material for both to get direction on Load balancing issues. Sometimes you wont find ALB when looking for details, so remember to check the ELB category too!

Most limits can be raised, but when it comes to things like ALB rules and for example Security Group rules these limits are put in place because there can be a performance impact if you go beyond the limits.

You can raise a limit request by going to the link below. Please do include a detailed "Use Case" in your request and give some thought to the value you are asking for (do not just ask for a random number).

This will help speed up the time it takes to receive your limit increases and will cut down on back and forth messaging (which is important if you are not on a paid support agreement!)

https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-elastic-load-balancers

**Additional Information**

Here are a couple links regarding Loadbalancer limits in your AWS account that you may also find useful:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-limits.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_elastic_load_balancer